# PHPQuery... trying to get all links of all images from page

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, phpquery

I am trying to get all links of all images on a given page using PHPQuery. I am using the PHP support syntax of PHPQuery.

This is the code I have so far:

```
include('phpQuery-onefile.php');

$all = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML("http://www.mysite.com", $charset = 'utf-8');

// in theory this gives me all image sources
$images = $all->find('img')->attr('src'); 

// but if I do `echo $images;` what I get is the src to the first image
```

Out of curiosity I have tried

```
$images = $all->find('img:first')->attr('src');
```

and

```
$images = $all->find('img:last')->attr('src');
```

and it prints correctly the first and the last image's addresses, respectively, but how in hell can I get an array of all links?

Comment: This must be done with phpquery? May not use e.g.file_get_contents/preg_match?

Comment: because phpquery is a lot easier to parse the code...

Comment: If src = relative, would phpquery give you absolute paths? Do you need absolute path like `http://...` if src is relative?

Comment: I need absolute paths... absolute to the site where the page is hosted. Anyway `echo $a->attr('src');` is getting me nothing. Why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$all->find("img");` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your foreach loop, you need to wrap the `$a` with a `pq()`.

For example:

```
$all = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML("http://www.mysite.com", $charset = 'utf-8');

$imgs = $all['img'];

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    // Note: $img must be used like "pq($img)"
    echo pq($img)->attr('src');
}
```

Comment: Nice, got it similar `foreach (pq('img') as $img) { echo pq($img)->attr('src'); }`